# Settings.Default alters the line-ending of Specialized.StringCollection elements

Tags: c#, .net, newline

I just came across a strange behavior of `Settings.Default` when using a setting of type `Specialized.StringCollection`.

The problem is whenever the settings are loaded (either by calling `.Reload()` or by restarting the application *--which I assume calls `Reload()` anyway*--), the elements of the `StringCollection` variable/setting have all the line-endings change from carriage-return and line-feed (`\r\n`) to only line-feed (`\n`).

**Here's a console app that demonstrates the problem:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.Foo == null)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Foo = 
            new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Foo.Add("Hello\r\nworld");
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    // Either call .Reload() or restart the application.
    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

    string currentValue = Properties.Settings.Default.Foo[0];
    Console.WriteLine(currentValue == "Hello\r\nworld");    // False
    Console.WriteLine(currentValue == "Hello\nworld");      // True

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Note that the actual value in the `.config` file doesn't really change *(unless, of course, we call `.Save()` again)*. It just seems that it gets "loaded" into the `StringCollection` in a wrong way.

**Is there something I'm missing?** Or is this a bug in the `Settings.Default` class (perhaps the `.Reload()` method) and I should manually change the line-endings each time the application starts?

Comment: It may be related to the internal use of `\r\n` in `Settings.Designer.cs`. This sequence is used to delimit the ArrayOfString. Allowing the same sequence inside the items might mess things up. Same thing if you use `\u000D\u000A` (since the Xml use Unicode encoding). It will return `\n` when reloaded. This could be a problem with a TextBox, but not with RichTextBox, which uses the more *compatible*  `\n` as line separator. Anyway, you can just split the string array and rebuild it as needed.

Comment: @Jimi But AFAIK, the settings are not loaded from `Settings.Desinger.cs`, they are loaded from the `user.config` XML file in `%LocalAppData%`. That XML file doesn't use line breaks to separate the elements of the `ArrayOfString`. Each element [has its own child node](https://s33.postimg.cc/z22ir21un/settings.png).

Comment: If you manually insert some data in the settings editor, it's stored in `Settings.Designer.cs` xml file. Since you have to define a *standard* to load these files content, a double standard is not convenient. It's a supposition. Another supposition is compatibility, since .Net has become multi-platform. All suppositions not because I'm lazy. Because I've searched an official reason and found nothing about it (if not other hypotheses). What's important is that this is a consistent behaviour, no matter where you store your data.

Comment: @Jimi, If you manually insert some data using the editor, it's not stored in `.Designer.cs` either, it's stored in the app.config/web.config file using the same XML structure. **Also**, this isn't a consistent behavior because if you have a variable/setting of type `String` which contains some `\r\n`, it stays `\r\n` after you reload the settings.

Comment: Visual Studio 15.7.3 here. Those settiings are store in both files (`Settings.Designer.cs` and `App.config`). I said consistent because this is what I could test. When you first store some strings with `\r\n` inside and you read the settings right after, you find `\r\n` in those strings. When you `.Save` the settings and then you reload them (or quit the program), you find `\n` alone. I don't remember having seen anything different (also tested passing the string to a TextBox and a RichTextBox).

Comment: It's an interesting question though. It's strange nobody else stopped by. If I can find something official I'll post it here.